# Access/Set filp->private_data member in probe() function

Tags: linux, driver, device, pci

General:
I am developing a **PCIE(PCI Express)** linux device driver with the `open()/close()/read()/write()` methods being implemented and the `probe()` function for the `PCIE` part.

Current situation:
Within the `probe()` function I have access to the `dev` pointer `driver_pcie_probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)` and through it I can do stuff like:

```
int my_pcie_probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
{
    int err = 0;
    int *bar0 = NULL;
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;

    // Before any device resources can be accessed, the device needs to be enabled.
    err = pci_enable_device(dev);
    if(err < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Unable to enable PCIe device!\n");
        return err;
    }

    // Request all BARs to this device.
    err = pci_request_regions(dev, MY_DRIVER_NAME);
    if(err) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Unable to request memory regions (BARs) from PCIe device!\n");
        return err;
    }

    // !!! TESTING !!!
    bar0 = pci_iomap(dev, 0, 0);
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        x = ioread32(bar0 + i);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "cycle: %d bar0: 0x%p, x = 0x%016x\n", i, bar0, x);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        iowrite32(i, bar0 + i);
    }
    // !!! TESTING !!!

    return err;
}
```

within the probe() function which works perfect.

What I want to do:
...is transfer the `iowrite/ioreads` into the character devices `read/write` methods.

```
ssize_t char_device_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    ssize_t ret = 0;
    struct my_device *my_dev;
    int device_buf[16];
    int i = 0;

    my_dev = filp->private_data;

    if (down_interruptible(&my_dev->sem)) {
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        device_buf[i] = ioread32(my_dev->BAR0 + i);
    }

    if (copy_to_user(buf, device_buf, count)) {
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    *f_pos += count;
    ret = count;

    up(&my_dev->sem);

    return ret;
}
```

**Problem**:
I need access to the `pci_dev struct *dev` within the character devices `read/write` method in order to do an `ioread/iowrite`.

What I know:
There is `filp->private_data` within the `read/write` methods of the character device, so I thought about having `my_own_device_struct` which I set the `filp->private_data` to. This way it's available within `open/close/read/write` of the character device.

What I thoughts works, but I can't figure out how:
I thought I can set the `filp->private_data->`... within the `probe()` function of the **PCIE** driver. This way the `*dev` (or at least the a `bar0` which is a member of `my_own_device_struct` is available for the `open/close/read/write` methods of the character device, but unfortunately this doesn't work and `dev_set_drvdata()` doesn't seem to do the job either.

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found so far is using a `struct my_own_device` with a `struct pci_dev` as member being initialized during the `probe()` function. It's just a static variable within my device driver module accessible from every function.

Since I have only one **PCIe** device that I am communicating with this might just be sufficient.

Comment: If anyone comes up with a better idea, I appreciate any more feedback on how this can be solved in a more "linux-way". Otherwise I'll mark this answer as a solution within the next days.

Comment: There is nothing in your question to help answer to. You need to provide a piece of code that shows how you create your character device node. With that, you may pass a pointer to the custom structure in which you can keep pointer to `struct pci_dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `iowrite()` you can use `kernel_write()`.

```
static struct file *filp;
```

open the file using `filp_open()`.

```
filp = filp_open();
```

Then you can use `kernel_write()`.

```
/* kernel_write(struct file *file, const char *buf, size_t count,loff_t pos); */
```

Comment: how does kernel_write() know about my devices BARs?

Comment: Or maybe it automatically enables all BARs of a device when used?

Comment: No it won't enable by default. do `cscope` on `kernel_write`, go to `definition` of `kernel_write` there you can find more information.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. As far as I understand it the kernel_write() will be translated into a `return file->f_op->write(file, p, count, pos);` which will call my `char_device_read` function. I am having trouble seeing how this helps me in making the `*dev` pointer within the `probe()` function available to my `char_device_read` function. Am I maybe missing sth.? Would you mind elaborating a bit how the kernel_write() call helps me transfering the `*dev` pointer over to my `char_device_read` function?